# Calling multiple functions in image upload form

Tags: php

I have an image upload form with which I call multiple functions before uploading the file such as checking the size and dimensions, and that it is in a valid image. The code works, but calling the functions and dealing with the results seems quite cumbersome and complex.

Is there a tidier way of structuring the code?

This is what I currently have:

```
//Upload an image
if(checkvalidfile("img",$ext)){
    if(checksize($size, 524288)) {
        if(checkdimensions($tmp, 300)) {
            $newfilename = renamefile($ext);
            recordfileindb($brand_id, $newfilename, $mysqli);
            uploadfile($tmp, $bucket, "user_docs/agency_".$agency_id."/brand_logos/", $newfilename, $s3);
            header('Location: ./message.php?action=newlogo'); 
        } else {
            echo "Your image can't be bigger than 300 x 300px";
            die;
        }
    } else {
        echo "File size is too big!";
        die;
    }
} else {
    echo "Not a valid file";
    die;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there's room for a lot of improvement here!

First of all, you can "break early" to avoid excessive indentation. Since `die` terminates the script, you can check if the file is **not** valid.

Secondly, instead of `echo`ing first and `die` later, you can call `die` with a parameter.

This code works in the same way, but is cleaner:

```
if (!checkvalidfile("img",$ext)) {
    die("Not a valid file");
}
if (!checksize($size, 524288)) {
    die ("File size is too big!");
}

if (!checkdimensions($tmp, 300)) {
    die("Your image can't be bigger than 300 x 300px");
}

$newfilename = renamefile($ext);
recordfileindb($brand_id, $newfilename, $mysqli);
uploadfile($tmp, $bucket, "user_docs/agency_".$agency_id."/brand_logos/", $newfilename, $s3);
header('Location: ./message.php?action=newlogo');
```